# Visualforce Page Permission for all Profiles

Tags: profile, xml, custom-profile

I want to provide **Visualforce Page** permission to all profiles (Custom and Standard) in one single shot.

I have 20 Profiles in the list and it will be tough to do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

1) Navigate to Visualforce Page from Global Search. 
2) Search for the VF which you want to provide profile access. 
3) Click on security in Actions section. 
4) Push the required profiles from left window to right window.

Comment: Hey Alp!! Welcome to SFSE, Great, It works, thanks!